# The selected content of a TextField can't be overwritten (in Java)

Tags: java

I have a TextField and when I select the content of the text field and try to change its value (by enetering a new value), nothing happens. I can change the content only after I delete the text field's content (either by hitting Delete or Backspace). I do have a regular expressions constraint set on that field. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand your question, a code will help.

Comment: Everything's done in an XML file so there's no code apart from the xml. My textfield has a numeric constraint and I also use regular expression ([01*], which means that the text field can accept only 0,1 and *. This all works fine except for the overwrite part. Let's say that the value of the text field is 1 and try to change it to 0. Now I can do that only if I delete 1 and enter 0. I want to be able to select the 1 (old/current value) and simply press 0 (new value) but this doesn't work. I have to stress that we do have our own Java framework so this might be the problem.

Comment: @Jasmann I can't till tomorrow (when I'm back in my office). I just wondered whether someone out there had a similar issue. I can get help in my company but it might take days and I'd rather resolve the issue myself.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys. I probably shoudn't have asked this question here. Anyway, it's solved , I just changed my regular expression to [01*]+ (instead of just [01*]).  Our framework suppots a web client and a Swing client and only the web client had this problem. Again sorry to have wasted your time